# Can I get off a plane at connecting flight?

Tags: visas, air-travel

I know this may be considered hidden-city ticketing and airlines have qualms with the practice, but since it's technically not illegal I was wondering if I bought a ticket from Chicago to Moscow with a plane change in Dusseldorf, Germany if I could just get off at Dusseldorf. Would I be able to check my bags only to Dusseldorf? Another problem is that Russia requires a visa, but since I'm not going all the way to Russia, would I still need to get one?

Another way of putting all this, is it feasible for me to travel this way?

Comment: This somewhat also depends on the airline and your luck. You will not always be able to convince the gate agent to check your baggage only to Dusseldorf. Note that the airline has the right to deny boarding if you don't have a visa to your final destination. So if you wanted to get off at DUS, you would be gambling that they are only checking your Russian visa in Dusseldorf, which is *very* risky.

Comment: @DCTLib Risky is probably understating it. If it's one ticket they always check at the originating point, in my experience.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Not always! On a trip from Central Europe to the US via London ~2 years ago, they performed the visa check for me in London at the "transfer desk".

Comment: I've not been checked for my visa plenty of times. So, risky.

Comment: you can get off and demand your bag if you like, but the visa issue will raise eyebrows at the origin.